# Fix wrong encoding of filenames

Tags: nautilus, encoding

strangely the encodings from some music I got from a friend with Windows 7 OS show up with a wrong encoding in nautlius . I already tried it with

```
convmv --notest -r -f windows-1255 -t utf-8 *
```

but it didn't fix it. It rather but another wrong encoding. I tried also with latin1 and latin3. Since I don't know what the original encoding was and I can't find that out, I keep wondering what my options are.

Thx for any advice.

Comment: if the files are mp3 they may hold strings inside the file with the artist and so on for you to recreate the filename. see `id3info` or similar tools.

Comment: @meuh  Yes they are mp3. id3info gives me: *** mp3 info
MPEG1/layer III
Bitrate: 192KBps
Frequency: 44KHz

Comment: that's a pity. typically id3info would find "tags" like TIT2 Title, TALB Album, and so on, but it doesnt seem like your files hold this information.

Comment: ok i tried out with other songs. It gives me: `=== TIT2 (Title/songname/content description): 22 - Selegco de Pagode` and `=== TALB (Album/Movie/Show title): CD Jads e Jadson - Ao Vivo em Maringa` but where is the encoding?

Comment: I thought you might just ignore the original file names and rename the files from the id3 tag info.

Comment: ups but its 1200 songs...

Answer (score 1):

To try all the encodings, choose one of your files, eg mychosenfile.mp3m, and then loop
through all the encodings. With luck you will find one that seems to be ok.
This just lists the possible new names:

```
file=mychosenfile.mp3
for enc in $(convmv --list)
do  echo $enc: $(convmv --parsable -f $enc -t utf-8 "$file")
done
```

---

Alternatively, you can rename the files to the song track and title taken from the id3 tag if they have one.
For example, (this just echo's the mv command):

```
find mydir -name '*.mp3' |
while read file
do if newname="$(id3info "$file" |
        awk -F': ' '
         /^=== TRCK/{ track = $2 }
         /^=== TIT2/{ title=$2;gsub(" ","_",title) }
         END        { if(title!="")printf "%02d_%s.mp3\n",track,title }
        ')"
   then dir=$(dirname "$file")
        echo mv "$file" "$dir/$newname"
   fi
done
```

Comment: thanks for your tips. I tried the first trick. quite nice. unfortunately it did not give any satisfactory result. the second one with renaming wont work because also the encoding inside the fileinfo is  wrong...unfortunatly.

Comment: Thanks for your first tip to try all encodings. This just saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

To remove special characters from all filenames, use `detox`:

```
detox -r -v -s utf8 /path/to/files/
```

You may also pass `-n` to see what it will done and verify it sounds sensible.

To rename all files according to their music tags, use `lltag`:

```
lltag -R --mp3v2 --mp3read=21 --rename '/new/path/%a/%A/%n %t' /path/to/files
```

You should consider passing `--dry-run` to first invocation to see what will be done; pass `--yes` if you are tired of answering questions (might affect quality of new names in case of missing tags and the like).

More details are in `man detox` and `man lltag`.

Comment: since I do not know which encoding the file is, `detox` produces wrong results. Something that should be `é` but was displayed as  `|` now appears as `_` .... the problem is that also inside the mp3 tags the encoding is wrong so `lltag` won't do the job as well... but thanks for the efforts. `detox` is good to remember for other tasks.

Comment: `detox` is used to change all problematic characters in file names to something that other tools will handle. If you don't like what it produces, you can rename files later on; probably automatically, but first you need to fix tags. You can try `easytag` (GUI app). It can try decode tag using specified encoding, so after some back and forth you might finally figure out what encoding this is and convert it to UTF8 (easytag will do that). Then you can rename all files according to tags - using `lltag` or `easytag`.